# Validações do Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

Não estou conseguindo encontrar onde Identity faz as validações, estou com problema quando vou cadastrar um novo usuário. Alguém sabe onde isso é validado ?

Comment: Mostra o erro cara que te retorna quando você tenta cadastrar, assim fica mais fácil de ajudar! Dê o máximo de informações possíveis!

Comment: O erro que aparece é "Name cannot be null or empty.",não faço idéia de onde está puxando.

Comment: @RaphaelGumm Esse erro é do mau. Já respondi em outra pergunta. Qualquer coisa me chama que eu reabro e dou uma resposta mais específica.

Comment: Ótimo, vou dar uma olhada. Qualquer coisa se não conseguir te comunico.